# Schema Compare failed: Unexpected exception caught during population of source model: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to prepare deployment script comparing Dev and QA Servers Db using ADS / VS 2019 in both cases I the below error..

Schema Compare failed: Unexpected exception caught during population of source model: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Have DB_owner permissions on both.

Comment: Does the user you are logging in with have sufficient permissions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.